# Split a file with macro in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, spreadsheet

I know there are 2 similar questions.
I have a very large Excel file separated in sections by 3 blanks lines.
I was wondering if there was a way to split the spreadsheet into other every time there is a blank in column A or every time the word "Section" appears in column A.

Comment: Split into separate worksheets or new Excel files?

Comment: a new excel file would be easier

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading the posting [Split Worksheet, Seperated By Blank Rows, Into Several Worksheets](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=137266)  and tailoring it to fit your needs.

This post should also be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556533/split-excel-sheets-to-multiple-workbooks.